# Google Api Gmail - strange emails

Tags: php, api, gmail

I am using this function for send emails.

```
function sendMessage($to, $subject, $messageBody, $Cc)
{
    $service = getGoogleGmailService();
    $message = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();

    $rawMessageString = "From: 'My name' <me>\r\n";
    $rawMessageString .= "To: <" . $to . ">\r\n";
    if (!empty($Cc)) {
        $rawMessageString .= "Cc: <" . $Cc . ">\r\n";
    }
    $rawMessageString .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . "?=\r\n";
    $rawMessageString .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $rawMessageString .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $rawMessageString .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $rawMessageString .= $messageBody . "\r\n";
    $rawMessage = strtr(base64_encode($rawMessageString), array('+' => '-', '/' => '_'));
    $message->setRaw($rawMessage);
    try {
        $message = $service->users_messages->send('me', $message);
        return $message->getId();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

In the first photo it is how the email should be structured, in fact everything arrives ok. Every so often, however, I receive a strange email, as in the second photo, as if it were still encoded or something else.
What could it be ?

[image: First image, as it should be]

[image: Second image, as it arrives sometimes]